# PostgresSQL - temporal difference between first and last revision of a report

Tags: postgresql

The table structure for my `report_history` table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "report_history"(
"pk"                 SERIAL          PRIMARY KEY,
"revision"           BIGINT,
"report_fk"          BIGINT,
"old_status_fk"      BIGINT,
"updatedby_fk"       BIGINT,
"updated_datetime"   TIMESTAMP,
"file_path"          TEXT,
"synopsis"           TEXT
);
```

while the `report` table itself is defined like so:

```
CREATE TABLE "report"(
"pk"                    SERIAL          PRIMARY KEY,
"report_uuid"           VARCHAR(32)     UNIQUE,
"study_fk"              BIGINT,
"status_fk"             BIGINT,
"priority_fk"           BIGINT,
"report_relative_path"  VARCHAR(256),
"report_type_fk"        BIGINT,
"createdby_fk"          BIGINT,
"created_datetime"      TIMESTAMP
);
```

What I'd like to know is how I could find the difference (in time) between the first revision of a report and the last revision of the same report? To clarify, in pesudocode, I would like to perform the following subtraction:

```
RETURN report_history.updated_datetime (newest) - report_history.updated_datetime
(oldest) WHERE report_fk = ?
```

Can any one help me solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post some sample data and the expected result based on the sample data. Ideally on http://sqlfiddle.com to make this very vague question a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is **very** vague, but something like this might get you started:

```
select r.*, rh.max_updated, rh.min_updated
from report as r
  join (
     select report_fk, 
            min(updated_datetime) as min_updated,
            max(updated_datetime) as max_updated
     from report_history
     group by report_fk
  ) as rh on rh.report_fk = r.pk;
```

Comment: sorry about that i am new to stack overflow

Comment: this is fetching the max an min revision but i want the values of the updated date time of the max revision and the min revision so that i wanted to find the difference between them can you can me

Comment: @SaravanaKumar: you should have stated that explicitely in your question. Ask a vague question and you get a wrong answer.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar: Sounds like simply replacing `min(revision)` by `min(updated_datetime)` would do what you want.